# Transfers between La Tontouta (NOU) airport and Noumea

Tags: airport-transfer, new-caledonia, nou

[La Tontouta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Tontouta_International_Airport), the international airport for Noumea, New Caledonia, is located 45 km from the city and I'm having a hard time finding good information about transport options.

With **two adults and two children under 12**, what would be the cheapest reliable option, and how much a premium would there be to take a private transfer instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There appear to be at least four ways to get from La Tontouta to Noumea:

- Public shuttles (*navette collective*), meets all flights, no reservations required but apparently make many stops to let off passengers, pricing from XPF 2500 per head ([Allo Transports](http://allotransports.com/tarifs/), [Navette les Mouettes](http://www.navette-lesmouettes.nc/))
- Private shuttles (*navettes*), around XPF 3000/head, from [various operators](http://www.cci.nc/aeroports/aeroport-de-noumea-la-tontouta/informations-pratiques-0); the only one I can find with a functioning website that has pricing is [Smith Voyage](http://smithvoyage.lagoon.nc/english.html), who quoted XPF 9500 for our group.
- Taxis, which have spotty availability and charge through the nose (XPF 10,000++)
- Public bus ([Carsud Ligne C](http://www.carsud.nc/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=568&Itemid=633)), roughly hourly Mon-Sat but only two services on Sunday, fare only XPF 280.  However, the airport buses terminate at Noumea's Desmazures terminal, so most visitors would need to connect to a different bus or take a taxi to get to their hotel.

In the end, we opted for **car rental** instead: rates from the usual suspects (Hertz, Europcar, Sixth etc) start around XPF 5000/day, meaning we could get almost four days' rental for the price of a private shuttle return.  Given that getting around greater Noumea on public transport is inconvenient to impossible, this was the right choice.

Comment: perhaps because the options are so suboptimal, many of the hotels include a shuttle service. Since the hotels charge per room and the shuttles per head, this may make it worthwhile to go for a slightly more expensive hotel.